# DeployCopier: add folder

Tags: ocean, petrel

Some dependencies of our plugin are required to be in a sub-folder of the plugin's directory.

What tag should be used in `DeployList.xml` so that some folder and all its contents well be added to the plugin?

At the moment we solve this by adding custom post build events to the DeployPlugin project.